# Using if statements in mysql statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using a generic wordpress sql statement to grab the post titles.  I want to replace the post titles with a postmeta value of the all in one seo plugin is an all in one seo title exists for the post.

How do I use this if statement in the sql command?

Existing code without the all in one if statement.

```
//Limit to last 30 days, 1,000 items                    
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt, $wpdb->posts.post_title
                    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
                    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status='publish' 
                    AND (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), post_date_gmt)<=30)
                    $includeMe
                    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt DESC
                    LIMIT 0, 1000");
```

**New Function That's Getting an Error Now after Phil's Answer**

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COALESCE($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, $wpdb->posts.post_title) AS post_title, $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt, $wpdb->posts.ID
                    FROM $wpdb->posts
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->post_meta
                    ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
                    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_aioseop_title' 
                    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status='publish' 
                    AND (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), post_date_gmt)<=30)
                    $includeMe
                    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt DESC
                    LIMIT 0, 1000");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) with a `LEFT JOIN` on the `post_meta` table. For example (note, generic query only, not directly related to Wordpress)

```
SELECT COALESCE(post_meta.value, posts.title) AS title
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_meta
ON posts.id = post_meta.post_id
AND post_meta.key = 'some_meta_key'
```

Comment: Cool thanks - never saw the coalesce() function before - going to try now.

Comment: Phil, I just changed my function and I'm getting an error - I'm about to post it back in the question - you mind taking a look?

Comment: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_aioseop' at line 4]

Comment: I think it's because of the WHERE directly after the ON variables

Comment: @Bob Is it `$wpdb->post_meta` or `$wpdb->postmeta`? You use both and I'm guessing the the latter is the valid one.

Comment: Thanks - not only was that there, but also, $wpdb-> wasn't being read in the other function, so I chnaged it to wp_ ...didn't know that's what $wpdb-> rendered - learn something new everyday - really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Bob `$wpdb` is an object and the properties contain the table names, including the configurable table prefix (default `wp_`). You should probably use the `$wpdb` properties if possible

Comment: I would like to, but I wasn't able to get functionality on a few different parts of it - I'll try to reconfigure - it was probably because of poor string building for a few of the variables.